# Android Studio: Open URL to restricted in-app browser

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio app development.

I have created a button in the app that opens a url in google chrome in an emulator. I want to make to that the url opens in such a way that the user is restricted to using only the link on the button. In other words, I don't want the url to open and the user being able to get out of the app of browse in other websites.

I am thinking maybe there is a way to open the url in an in-app browser rather than the link leading the app to something like Google Chrome?

Comment: You could use [setWebViewClient()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)) and [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

Comment: @zomega together?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the Android Developer WebView guide? [Developer Guide - WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

In your XML you can add the WebView to the activity layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

In your class:

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")
```

Your app will also need access to the internet, so in Manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: For local html files, the last part is not needed, right? The directory is local.